# Python/Pandas: reshape and merge dataframes, with some matching of elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Question**

I have two input dataframes (DataFrame 1 and 2) like the ones shown below. I need to bring them together to create a third dataframe (DataFrame 3) that contains information from both.

How can I do this?

**Input datasets**

*Input dataset one: DataFrame 1*

[image: df1]

```
data1 = [{'grp': 2131, 'grp_n': "Materials", 'service_sk': 21311, 'service': "service, one", 'factor': "Detroit", 'output': 0.81959042}, 
             {'grp': 2131, 'grp_n': "Materials", 'service_sk': 21311, 'service': "service, one", 'factor': "Pittsburgh", 'output':None},
             {'grp': 2131, 'grp_n': "Materials", 'service_sk': 21312, 'service': "service, two", 'factor': "Detroit", 'output': 1.5038647},
             {'grp': 2131, 'grp_n': "Materials", 'service_sk': 21312, 'service': "service, two", 'factor': "Pittsburgh", 'output':None},
             {'grp': 1113, 'grp_n': "Machines", 'service_sk': 11131, 'service': "service, three", 'factor': "Detroit", 'output':None},
             {'grp': 1113, 'grp_n': "Machines", 'service_sk': 11131, 'service': "service, three", 'factor': "Pittsburgh", 'output':None},
             {'grp': 1113, 'grp_n': "Machines", 'service_sk': 11132, 'service': "service, four", 'factor': "Detroit", 'output': 1.7252077},
             {'grp': 1113, 'grp_n': "Machines", 'service_sk': 11132, 'service': "service, four", 'factor': "Pittsburgh", 'output': 1.6642461},
             {'grp': 1113, 'grp_n': "Machines", 'service_sk': 11133, 'service': "service, five", 'factor': "Detroit", 'output':None},
             {'grp': 1113, 'grp_n': "Machines", 'service_sk': 11133, 'service': "service, five", 'factor': "Pittsburgh", 'output': 1.4525868},
             ]
 # Input dataframe 1
 df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

*Input dataset two: DataFrame 2*

[image: df2]

```
data2 = [{'grp_n': "Materials", 'c_Detroit': 104, 'c_Pittsburgh': 184, 'i_service, two': 18.5241, 'i_service, one': 10.1906, 'i_service, four': 1, 'i_service, five': 1}, 
        {'grp_n': "Machines", 'c_Detroit': 56, 'c_Pittsburgh': 89, 'i_service, two': 1, 'i_service, one': 1, 'i_service, four': 24, 'i_service, five': 34.534}
       ]
# Input dataframe 2
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

**Result I am after**

*DataFrame 3*

[image: df3]

Note that elements under the `service_sk` and `service` columns are related to elements in the `grp` and `grp_n` columns.

**Background**

I looked into using `melt` to transform the input datasets from wide to long format, but this scenario is particularly tricky given that some matching of table elements is required.

I also tried `df3=df1.merge(df2.reset_index(), right_on='grp_n',left_on='grp_n',how='left')` which merges  both dataframes, but the resulting structure is not the one I am after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have to take a couple of steps to get what you want.

First of all you must transform the dataframe 2 to a different format, you can do this in different ways, what I find as a good move would be to transform the dataframe in 2 different dataframes.

Obtain a dataframe of the factories indicator using melt:

```
df2_factory = df2[['grp_n','c_Detroit','c_Pittsburgh']].copy()
df2_factory.columns = df2_factory.columns.str.lstrip('c_')
df2_factory = pd.melt(df2_factory, id_vars=['grp_n'], value_vars=['Detroit','Pittsburgh'], 
                      var_name ='factor', value_name='indicator_p')
```

Obtain a dataframe of the services indicator using melt:

```
df2_service = df2[['grp_n','i_service, two','i_service, one','i_service, four','i_service, five']]
df2_service.columns = df2_service.columns.str.lstrip('i_')
df2_service = pd.melt(df2_service, id_vars=['grp_n'], value_vars=['service, two','service, one','service, four','service, five'], 
                      var_name ='service', value_name='indicator_i')
```

After this, you can us this 2 new dataframes to merge with the original data:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2_factory, how='left', right_on=['grp_n','factor'], left_on=['grp_n','factor'])
df3 = df3.merge(df2_service, how='left', right_on=['grp_n','service'], left_on=['grp_n','service'])
```

This should give you the data you want in the format you want

[image]

Comment: This is fantastic. Thanks so much. Follow-up question, I should have specified that my list 'Factory' and 'service' is a lot more extensive than in my examples. Is there a way to have a more general solution that listing each 'factory' and 'service' individually? I actually added the 'c_' and 'i_' prefixes to each 'factory' and 'service' column in dataframe 2 hoping this would help produce a more general solution, but not sure if it really helps. Any advice on this would be beneficial, and thanks again for the above.

Comment: that would mean that the number of columns in the df2 would increase by a big number, there are ways to handle this, but the biggest issue would be to create a list with all the columns with names of factories and services (for example, drop the gnr_p column and then create a list with all the factories.columns). After that you simply replace the values in value_vars with the list and that should work (haven't tested)

Comment: Thanks. This is what I ended up doing although I saved the values as a tuple rather than list.

Answer (score 0):

My solution uses **iteration**, so, it may be slower than the other answers:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df3 = df1.copy()

df3[['indicator_p', 'indicator_j']] = np.nan
#print(df3.columns)

for grp in ['Materials', 'Machines']:
    # for indicator_p
    for factor in ['Detroit', 'Pittsburgh']:
        df3.loc[((df3['grp_n']==grp) & (df3['factor']==factor)), 'indicator_p'] = \
            df3.loc[((df3['grp_n']==grp) & (df3['factor']==factor)), 'indicator_p'].fillna(df2.loc[df2['grp_n']==grp, 'c_'+factor].values[0])        
    # for indicator_i
    for serv in ['service, one', 'service, two', 'service, four', 'service, five']:
        df3.loc[((df3['grp_n']==grp) & (df3['service']==serv)), 'indicator_j'] = \
            df3.loc[((df3['grp_n']==grp) & (df3['service']==serv)), 'indicator_j'].fillna(df2.loc[df2['grp_n']==grp, 'i_'+serv].values[0])

print(df3)
```

The above code assumes that the required `dataframe`s, `df1` and `df2` have already been defined. The output will be:

```bash
      dtype='object')
    grp      grp_n  service_sk  ...    output indicator_p  indicator_j
0  2131  Materials       21311  ...  0.819590       104.0      10.1906
1  2131  Materials       21311  ...       NaN       184.0      10.1906
2  2131  Materials       21312  ...  1.503865       104.0      18.5241
3  2131  Materials       21312  ...       NaN       184.0      18.5241
4  1113   Machines       11131  ...       NaN        56.0          NaN
5  1113   Machines       11131  ...       NaN        89.0          NaN
6  1113   Machines       11132  ...  1.725208        56.0      24.0000
7  1113   Machines       11132  ...  1.664246        89.0      24.0000
8  1113   Machines       11133  ...       NaN        56.0      34.5340
9  1113   Machines       11133  ...  1.452587        89.0      34.5340

[10 rows x 8 columns]
```